Drawio CSV to MAP
See here an example how I would like the map to be shown.
Drawio example
I am trying to insert something looking like this as a CSV import to drawio.
In the middle should be "Advertising" and then spreading to Marketing, Communication, Organization which have also several additional leaves.
How should this CSV look like and what are the style commands for a map like in the picture
I am aware of the import command via arrange-> insert -> advanced. But with the CSV order and style commands for the map I'm lost.
Thank very much in advance.
